# AspNet Identity RequireUniqueEmail = false throws exception on CreateAsync

Tags: asp.net-identity, unique, owin

I initialize `UserValidator` of the `UserManager` with `RequireUniqueEmail=false`, the validator accepts duplicate emails for sure (tried to inherit it and override the `ValidateAsync()` method).
However, when I try to create another user with a unique `UserName` but with an `Email` that already exists in the `AspNetUsers` table, `CreateAsync()` throws

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

There is just one validation error:

> Email myemail@email.com is already taken.

I've checked the properties of the `UserValidator` before `CreateAsync` and `RequireUniqueEmail=false`, so it's initialized correctly.
Funny thing is when I set `RequireUniqueEmail` to `true` it won't throw an exception, only return `IdentityResult` with the same error message in it.

`Owin v.3.1.0` is used (same with v.3.0.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long and deep research and debugging I've found that you not only have `RequireUniqueEmail` flag in your `UserValidator`, but also same flag in your `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, and they both should have the same value.